# Xamarin Android: Cannot embed jna-4.2.0.jar into an Android Binding project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I'm trying to embed some jars from a native project into my Xamarin Android app, and I have hit two separate (but I suspect related) problems:

1. One of the files in the package is jna-4.2.0.jar. When I try to build the binding project on its own, I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ICallback' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sun.Jna' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The generated code is as follows:

```
    [Register ("getCallback", "(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/jna/Pointer;)Lcom/sun/jna/Callback;", "")]
    public static unsafe global::Com.Sun.Jna.ICallback GetCallback (global::Java.Lang.Class type, global::Com.Sun.Jna.Pointer p)
    {
        if (id_getCallback_Ljava_lang_Class_Lcom_sun_jna_Pointer_ == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_getCallback_Ljava_lang_Class_Lcom_sun_jna_Pointer_ = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID (class_ref, "getCallback", "(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/jna/Pointer;)Lcom/sun/jna/Callback;");
        try {
            JValue* __args = stackalloc JValue [2];
            __args [0] = new JValue (type);
            __args [1] = new JValue (p);
            global::Com.Sun.Jna.ICallback __ret = global::Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Com.Sun.Jna.ICallback> (JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod  (class_ref, id_getCallback_Ljava_lang_Class_Lcom_sun_jna_Pointer_, __args), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
            return __ret;
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

I have also tried downloading the latest version, jna-4.4.0.jar, from https://github.com/java-native-access/jna, but that generates the same error.

2. The library I'm using generates this error:

> 'Version' does not implement interface member
>   'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)'

I have tried to solve this issue, following the Xamarin documentation, and using the comments in the generated `cs` files, by adding this line to the `metadata.xml` file in my bindings project:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.innovatrics.iface']/class[@name='Version']/method[@name='compareTo' 
    and count(parameter)=1 
    and parameter[1][@type='com.innovatrics.iface.Version']]" 
    name="managedType">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

but this seems to have had no effect at all.

Comment: have you ever found good solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you try to change the classname in this case?

Try to add the following in the `Metadata.xml` file (untested):

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.sun.jna']/interface[@name='Callback']" name="name">ICallback</attr>
```

This will change the interface name from `Callback` in Java to `ICallback` in C#

Answer (score 0):

Using the above rename method, i was able to get past this, but found a few more errors when also attempting to Bind the JNA Jar file.

I wanted to know, how much further you got with this, and if possible could share the Metadata.xml file that allowed you to complete this binding please ?

Comment: do you have any update on this? long time but if you remember?